# Complex query / Index help for MongoDB query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I have a big mongodb query that has some dynamic properties based on filter options, and including filtering between dates. My query is currently causing scanned Objects / returned results ratio to go above 1000. I am sure my query can be improved as well as adding suitable indexes but I am not sure of the correct index's / improvements to my query.

```
const userFilter = user ? { assignee: new Types.ObjectId(user) } : null;
    const clientFilter = client ? { client: new Types.ObjectId(client) } : null;

Collection.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                ...userFilter,
                ...clientFilter,
                status: 1,
                customer: new Types.ObjectId(customer),
            },
        },
        {
            $match: {
                $or: [
                    {
                        end: {
                            $gte: new Date(end),
                        },
                        start: {
                            $lte: new Date(start),
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        end: {
                            $gte: new Date(end),
                        },
                        start: {
                            $lte: new Date(end),
                            $gte: new Date(start),
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        start: {
                            $lte: new Date(start),
                        },
                        end: {
                            $lte: new Date(end),
                            $gte: new Date(start),
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        start: {
                            $gte: new Date(start),
                        },
                        end: {
                            $lte: new Date(end),
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        start: {
                            $lte: new Date(end),
                        },
                        // @ts-ignore
                        start: {
                            $gte: new Date(start),
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        end: {
                            $lte: new Date(end),
                        },
                        // @ts-ignore
                        end: {
                            $gte: new Date(start),
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        },
        {
            $sort: { createdAt: 1 },
        },

}
```

Depending on filter options we could be filtering by assignee and/or client.
We also only want returned results where the start or end date of the document falls within the start and end date filters.

I have tried a few variations of the query itself, as well as adding some compound indexes but had no real success improving the query or index's.

Comment: Check the explain plan by adding option `aggregate([...], {explain: true})`

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but a bit too long for a comment:

Do you really like conditions like

```
{
    $match: {
       null,
       null,
       status: 1,
       customer: new Types.ObjectId(customer),
    },
}
```

Or should you better use:

```
let match = {
   status: 1,
   customer: new Types.ObjectId(customer)
};

if (user) 
   match.assignee = new Types.ObjectId(user);
if (client) 
   match.client = new Types.ObjectId(client);

Collection.aggregate([
     { $match: match },
     ...
```

I never tried, perhaps `{$match: null}` prevents any index use.